# Errors happen when use clang-format.py in vim

Tags: vim, clang-format

I follow the steps in http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html and use `ctrl + k` to use `clang-format.py`. I get errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/.local/clang-format.py", line 106, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/.local/clang-format.py", line 84, in main
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is the python info in vim:

```
$ vim --version | grep python
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
```

Anybody help?

Comment: It tries to run `clang-format` binary. Do you have one? Can you run it directly?

Comment: yes I can. But I do not known why error happens. Then I use vs code, It works.